# Refresh jstree after `load_node` with updated json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I have a jstree element which loads data from a json array called `hpo_json` when being initialised at `init_hpotree()`. Then on a specific button click I pass the json array (`hpo_json`) to an ajax call, receive the updated array and then reinitialise the jstree. Everything work absolutely fine.

```
hpo_json = [...]
function init_hpotree() {
    jstree_hpo = $('#jstree_hpo').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : [hpo_json]
        }
    });
}

function destroy_hpotree() {
    $("#jstree_hpo").jstree("destroy");    
}

$('button.btnAdd').click(() => {
    destroy_hpotree();
    ajax_call(hpo_json) -> update -> hpo_json
    init_hpotree();
});
```

But I also need to update the contents of json array (`hpo_json`) and expand the tree when you click on a particular node. So I edited my initialise function as follows:

```
function init_hpotree() {
    jstree_hpo = $('#jstree_hpo')
    .on('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        ajax call -> update -> hpo_json
    })
    .jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : [hpo_json]
        }
    });
}
```

The `hpo_json` array is updated but I'm not sure how to refresh the tree. Some of the *SO* answers suggest using `tree.jstree("refresh")` but i'm not sure where exactly.FYI, I'm using `jsTree - v3.3.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tree.redraw([full])` :

redraws all nodes that need to be redrawn or optionally - the whole tree

https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=redraw([full])

Maybe like this :

```
function init_hpotree() {
    jstree_hpo = $('#jstree_hpo').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : [hpo_json]
        }
    });
    $('#jstree_hpo').jstree.redraw();
}
```

For the `load_node (obj [, callback])` function, something like this :

https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=load_node(obj%20[,%20callback])

loads a node (fetches its children using the core.data setting). Multiple nodes can be passed to by using an array.

```
 function load_node(node) {
      node.core.data = [hpo_json];

      jstree_hpo = $('#jstree_hpo').jstree.load_node(
         node,
         // Callback executed after node loading event.
         () => {
            $('#jstree_hpo').jstree.redraw();
         }
      );
  }
```

Get your node `get_node (obj [, as_dom])` :

https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_node(obj%20[,%20as_dom])

get the JSON representation of a node (or the actual jQuery extended DOM node) by using any input (child DOM element, ID string, selector, etc)

Comment: Thank you but could you please point out where exactly I should add this line?

Comment: I need to update (or redraw) my tree after the `load_node ` event.